# Describing the homotopy explicitly.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, knot-theory

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Let $X$ be a based space, and let $PX = \{ \beta: I \to X | \beta(0) = *\}.$ Show that $p_1: PX \to X$ by $p_1(\beta) = \beta(1)$ is a based fibration.

I am confused about what should be the exact homotopy that I should write, here is a trial:

We have the following commutative diagram:

> [image]

and here is a trial to the homotopy I should write:

$H'(y,s)(t) = \begin{cases}
f(y) \left( \frac{2t}{2-s} \right) & 0 \leq t \leq 1- \frac{s}{2},\\
H(y, 2(t-1)+s) & 1- \frac{s}{2} \leq t \leq 1.
 \end{cases}$

Is this a correct homotopy or not? Can it be written and thought of in a more organized and systematic way.

**Edit for Anne:**

You draw a square like below and then you draw your homotopy as a line joining s(down) with s(up) then you determine the coordinates of the points on both the s axes and then you calculate the equation of the line joining the points on the x-axes which help in determining the point at which your homotopy changes its definition.

[image]

**EDIT 2 for Anne :**

> [image]

Is this what you meant Anne?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked your homotopy and I think it is correct. The following seems to be correct also (?), and simpler:
$$H'(y,s)(t) = \begin{cases}
f(y)(s+t) & s+t\le1,\\
H(y,s+t-1) & s+t\ge1.
 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you draw yours for me by a square with the beginning point of the line and the end point please?  ...... Also, how did you check mine? Can you draw it also with a square please?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to draw on a PC. (Anyway, I don't understand what you want me to draw.) What I checked (on both) is that it is consistent in the limit case, and that it makes the diagram commute.

Comment: I mean how did you construct your homotopy? people usually draw a square with t as the horizontal (x - coordinate ) and s as the vertical (y - coordinate) and express the homotopy in terms of this ........... you can use quiver https://q.uiver.app/  on your laptop, I will edit my post to include an example of a picture of a homotopy like in Harpreet Bedi video "Path in space to fundamental group" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVxPwbUCep0&list=PLCgncMh0TrClLOU991FDEQK5LF_Aqm4FS&index=5   min. 6

Comment: The example in your video is not of the same nature. I don't see how to adapt this way of drawing to picture usefully your $H'$ or mine.

Comment: I mean can you tell me the intuition that leads you to write your homotopy like this please?

Comment: How did you get $s+t$ in your homotopy? and how did you get $s+t-1$?

Comment: I drew a square with $f$ on the left vertical edge and $H$ on the upper horizontal edge. Then a diagonal from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0),$ and then horizontal segments on the right of this diagonal, all along, with $H$ written on them, and vertical segments underneath with $f$ written on them. All these segments were of length 1 but I cut them to retain only the part lying inside the square.

Comment: I will try to draw your homotopy square (in an hour) and add it in my post ..... please confirm if it is correct or correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is something like that but the right vertical $f$ should be one step below. Actually, there are an infinity of vertical $f$'s, all below the diagonal, and (between the two you drew) an infinity of horizontal $H$'s, all above the diagonal.

Comment: What do you mean by one step and why it should be like this?

Comment: Your right vertical $f$ should be the segment from $(1,-1)$ to $(1,0)$ because above, there are the horizontal segments representing $H.$ This is only one way (among many others, like yours) to fill the square, given the left vertical segment $f$ and the upper horizontal segment $H$ (compatible at their common point $(0,1)$ since $H(y,0)=f(y)(1)$) imposed by the commuting diagram.

Comment: got it thank you very much!